# openssl issue xampp and laravel set up

Tags: ubuntu, laravel, xampp, laravel-4

I am trying to set up laravel locally on my pc. I am having error below.

I got a warning:

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/php_openssl.so' - /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/php_openssl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Then an error:
[RuntimeException]
  You must enable the openssl extension to download files via https

I am using xampp in ubuntu OS and I was not able to find any solution on how can I fix this.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: There is a stack called AMPPS which allows users to install Laravel in a single click. www.ampps.com . Hope that helps.

Comment: Under system requirements it says: Supported Operating Systems are Windows 7, Windows Vista SP2, Windows XP SP3+, Windows Server 2003 SP2+, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2. So this doesn't help me. sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally figured this out. I have another PHP installed so instead I used `/opt/lampp/bin/php` instead of just php so that I will be able to use the PHP in my xampp directory.

Now, I just need to change my $PATH variable so that I will be able to just run php again.

Thanks t myself! lolz! I feel so good today!

Answer (score 0):

Never used xampp, but it should be as simple as removing the # in your `httpd.conf` file

```
#LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
```

and restarting apache :)

Edit: Just realised it's a PHP error, try removing the ; from your php.ini

```
; extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Comment: sorry. that did not work... is that applicable to ubuntu OS as well?